# Sybase remote server to oracle: "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc, windows-server-2008, sybase-asa

I'm trying to setup a remote server on a sybase ASA 12 database (64bit) that connects to a oracle database (11g). 
Therefore I created an ODBC dataSource with the Orcale instantclient_11_2 driver. The connection test was successful. Name: "DMS_old"

Now I created a remote server:

```
CREATE SERVER "oracleDMS" 
CLASS 'ORAODBC' 
USING 'dms_old';
```

But when I test the connection of the server I get this error message:

> "[Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Unable to connect to server
>   'oracleDMS': [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified SQLCODE: -656 SQLSTATE: HY000"

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

OS: Windows Server 2008 (x64)

Br

Comment: I don't get this, a Sybase client connected to an Oracle server, using ODBC?

Comment: Please look at the sybase docoumentation: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315711.htm
 >> Example 3 << It is described like above.

Comment: Seems like I'm a bit behind... Can you find that oracleDMS if you start the ODBC manager? (Aren't there both a 32 bit ODBC manager, and a 64 bit ODBC manager?)

Comment: Yes, the connection test in the odbc manager is successful. As a precaution I added the oracle ODBC in 64bit manager and 32bit Manager.